# request-html return incorrect page with correct url

Tags: url, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I've had a practice on scraping with **requests-html** package under python 3.6. I've tried relevant websites but only one, **poetryfoundation.org, https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/browse#page=1&sort_by=recently_added&topics=20**, returns the incorrect page. I'll demonstrate it in detail.

Here is the source code, **the code just import requests-html and return poems which is wrapped in** :
    from requests_html import HTMLSession

```
class Scrapy:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def request_content(self, url):
        page = self.session.get(url)
        results = page.html.find('div.c-feature')
        a = True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = HTMLSession()
    scrapy = Scrapy(session)

    url = 'https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/browse#page=1&sort_by=recently_added&topics=20'
    scrapy.request_content(url=url)
```

**no matter what parameter I change the parameter in the url, it will just return one incorrect page**

Thanks for your time

Comment: because they are using dynamic data,

Comment: @kcorlidy Could you please show some reference about dynamic data or is there any solution to solve this problem! Thanks!

Comment: using selenium and webdriver should use chrome(i like PhantomJS but selenium does not suggest it)

Answer (score 0):

it is different page when you use `requests` and `selenium`,because website is using javascript to process the data

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
url = 'https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/browse#page=1&sort_by=recently_added&topics=20'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as ses:
        headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Referer": "https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/browse",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
}

        req = ses.get(url,headers=headers)
        A = req.text

    dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    dr.get(url)
    B = dr.page_source
    dr.close()
    print(type(A) == type(B))
    print(A == B)
    print(len(A),len(B))
```

Output

```
True # type(A) == type(B)
False # A == B
365477 482831
```